# Twitter "tweet this" button shows up as a button in Firefox, simply a link in Chrome

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, twitter

I can copy Twitter's "Tweet this" button examples straight form their website, and they don't work for me in Chrome. They work in Firefox. Does anybody know why?

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-related="jasoncosta" data-lang="en" data-size="large" data-count="none">Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

In Firefox, I get an actual button. In Chrome, I get a regular hyperlink that doesn't work. It seems the JavaScript to turn the link into a button is never running, but I'm not sure how to fix that.

Comment: If you open Chrome's developer tools are there any errors in the JavaScript console or the network tab?

Comment: @abraham I checked the console but didn't find any errors related to the JavaScript. There were a couple of errors about a different part of the page with an issue between the mime type of a google map I'm loading, but I don't think that's interfering.

Comment: @Jim I am facing the same problem. Can you please guide me how you solved it. I want the tweet button in chrome. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I had previously installed the Disconnect 3.1.1 plugin. This was screwing up Twitter's JavaScript. Disabling the plugin made the buttons start to work.